# Why does using '<div />' as the object in a JQuery UI dialog box method work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Consider the following code that creates a JQuery UI dialog box:

```
    function showBox()  {
      $('<div />').html('This is my dialog').dialog({
         buttons: {
           'Okay': function(){
              $(this).dialog('close');
           },
          'Return': function(){ 
              $(this).dialog('close'); 
           }
         },
         close: function(){ $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); },
         modal: true,
         title: 'My Dialog Title',
         width: 350
       });
    }
```

And a simple link in the body of an HTML page:

```
<a href="#" onClick="showBox()">Click to open a box</a>
```

The code works perfectly to launch a JQuery UI dialog.

My question is: Why does using `<div />` as the `$()` parameter actually generate a working box?

I have always used `<div></div>` as my `$()` parameter for dialogs. In HTML, div's are block-level elements that need an opening and closing tag, so why is using only `<div />` a valid option?

Comment: You can also use `$('<div>')`

Comment: @Tim Interesting. Do you know why that works without having to close the tag?

Comment: it doesn't expect it to be valid html. It only has to know what tag you want.

Comment: because this is jquery spirit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's how [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) was designed to work:

> In most cases, jQuery
>   creates a new  element and sets the innerHTML property of the
>   element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has
>   a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$( "<img
>   />" )` or `$( "<img>" )`, `$( "<a></a>" )` or `$( "<a>" )` — jQuery creates
>   the element using the native JavaScript createElement() function.

So when creating an element in jQuery, all of these are equivalent:

- `<div></div>`
- `<div />`
- `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases like this jquery parses the passed string by itself, and it doesn't distinguish between elements that need opening/closed tags and elements that don't need them.